# Unclassified Error when posting to Microsoft Connector Service when using Microsoft Teams

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, botframework

When I post to the Connector Service after receiving a message from Microsoft teams I am getting a 404 response with this in the body.

```
{"error":{"code":"Unclassified","message":""}}
```

The service is working with skype and was working with teams until about 10 days ago.

I have tried both the ReplyToActivity and RespondToConversation endpoints. I also tried encoding the : in the conversation.id.

The code can be see here: https://github.com/Grungnie/microsoftbotframework/blob/FixTeamsError732/microsoftbotframework/response.py in the method reply_to_activity.

**The message received from Microsoft** (id tags changed slightly)

```
{
   "text": "Test Message",
   "textFormat": "plain",
   "type": "message",
   "timestamp": "2017-03-27T11:55:33.983Z",
   "id": "1490615736123",
   "channelId": "msteams",
   "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac-client-ss.msg/",
   "from": {
      "id": "29:10U0pO0yzCqc_TZQImyaX1JGhe9KWpagDIwqtTl0moeT2lNC4PMrm9B2W_0w-Cr9tr5rty8vEZErb4yoyautked",
      "name": "Matthew Brown"
   },
   "conversation": {
      "id": "a:1lRzVTZeip__5jthfxCqiWX8koXTOg5OsFsnefe2kesHxvJAcJxNJs-TT3NvR1ote1PZZ_DQVkd5u5wsKmw2TQy53bvXOlXydDJjUUcolfphZWu2N-HuX8181rfRIMj7Q"
   },
   "recipient": {
      "id": "28:5e21d7a8-d1b5-4534-f549-f521712f5a64",
      "name": "PythonBotFramework"
   },
   "entities": [
      {
         "locale": "en-AU",
         "country": "AU",
         "platform": "Android",
         "type": "clientInfo"
      }
   ],
   "channelData": {
      "tenant": {
         "id": "5ghtef8a-55a8-4263-bd84-e03688a2ab2d"
      }
   }
}
```

Headers

```
Host: microsoftbotframework.herokuapp.com
Connection: close
Contextid: tcid=5448949784053522007, server=EAP010254248242
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ....
User-Agent: Microsoft-SkypeBotApi (Microsoft-BotFramework/3.0)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Request-Id: 6d8510c4-e3ba-4e34-80b2-45305a38d022
X-Forwarded-For: 13.75.95.64
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
Via: 1.1 vegur
Connect-Time: 0
X-Request-Start: 1490615736123
Total-Route-Time: 0
Content-Length: 747
```

**My Response**
URL

```
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/v3/conversations/a:1lRzVTZeip__5jthfxCqiWX8koXTOg5OsFsnefe2kesHxvJAcJxNJs-TT3NvR1ote1PZZ_DQVkd5u5wsKmw2TQy53bvXOlXydDJjUUcolfphZWu2N-HuX8181rfRIMj7Q/activities/1490615736123
```

Headers

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAgibJ....
```

Body

```
{
   "from": {
      "id": "28:5e21d7a8-d1b5-4534-f549-f521712f5a64",
      "name": "PythonBotFramework"
   },
   "type": "message",
   "timestamp": "2017-03-27T11:55:36.463971Z",
   "conversation": {
      "id": "a:1lRzVTZeip__5jthfxCqiWX8koXTOg5OsFsnefe2kesHxvJAcJxNJs-TT3NvR1ote1PZZ_DQVkd5u5wsKmw2TQy53bvXOlXydDJjUUcolfphZWu2N-HuX8181rfRIMj7Q"
   },
   "recipient": {
      "id": "29:10U0pO0yzCqc_TZQImyaX1JGhe9KWpagDIwqtTl0moeT2lNC4PMrm9B2W_0w-Cr9tr5rty8vEZErb4yoyautked",
      "name": "Matthew BROWN"
   },
   "text": "How bout no",
   "replyToId": "1490615736123",
   "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac-client-ss.msg/",
   "channelId": "msteams",
   "channelData": {
      "tenant": {
         "id": "5ghtef8a-55a8-4263-bd84-e03688a2ab2d"
      }
   },
   "textFormat": "plain"
}
```

** Updated after the error code changed on the 29/3. Previous error code below.

```
{"errorCode":732,"message":""}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a mistake,

```
response_url = urljoin(self["serviceUrl"], "/v3/conversations/{}/activities/{}".format( conversation_id, reply_to_id))
```

urljoin is stripping the last part of the url off self["serviceUrl"]. This is the expected behaviour. There doesn't seem to be a method that joins 2 parts of a url together. I wanted to do this as microsoft sometimes sends the url ending with a "/" and sometimes not. I guess I will just write my own method.